# innerHTML by node id

Tags: javascript

In javascript, when I replace content of node of  `id="demo"` by using `getElementById("demo").innerHTML="SOME TEXT";`  I get a strange problem that it's effect is lasting for only a few seconds. When I add a alert box for the same along with the above, the effect can be seen on background screen untill the alertbox is closed by clicking on 'OK'. Can someone suggest a solution to How I can make it remain there without getting changed untill I refresh the page ..)

Hi all,my code is a simple sort program as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var num=new Array(12,5,8,23,1);
var len;
function sort(){
len= num.length;
for(i=0; i<len-1; i++){
  for(j=0; j<len-i; j++){
    if(num[j]>num[j+1]){
     var tem=num[j];
     num[j]= num[j+1];
     num[j+1]= tem;
    }    
}
}
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=num;
alert(num);
}
</script>                                                                                           <form>
        <p id="demo">Click the button</p>
        <input type="submit" onclick="sort();" value="Click"></input>
     </form>
```

Comment: can you share some of your code?

Comment: Try putting "return false;" at the end of your function.

Comment: Something else in your code is changing the innerHTML property of the given element after you have made your changes. Can you share the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

check this link dude
http://jsfiddle.net/QXe7K/1/

the code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = userInput;
}
</script>
<p>Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff2'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter Text Here' />
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Change Text'/>​
```